# How can i Import & Export attributes & attribute set through import fuctionality in magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I need to Import/Export attributes and attribute sets from Magento admin (2.0)
 & trying to make new import functionality through extending the        `\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity`

**CSV content these values**

> EntityTypeId, attribute_set, attribute_name, attribute_group_name, is_global,
>   is_user_defined, is_filterable, is_visible, is_required, is_visible_on_front,
>   is_searchable, is_unique, is_configurable, frontend_class,
>   is_visible_in_advanced_search, is_comparable, is_filterable_in_search,  is_used_for_price_rules, position, frontend_input, backend_type,    frontend_label, default_value, apply_to, attribute_options

Comment: https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexport this will help?

Comment: I am trying to make new import functionality through extending the  \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity

Comment: hi, did you got any solution to it